# Unable to check for row state(locked or not) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, locking

In my application I need to make a lock on some rows when those are edited. If another user will make a select on that rows, his query will need to wait until first user release the lock. My problem is that i need to see if query is waiting, so in that case to be able for making an appointment for user that makes the query. Do you have any suggetion for this scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What storage engine does the table use?

Comment: I'm using InnoDB storage engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Transactions in MySQL, and if you use a recent version of MySQL (>5.1) the row locks will be set by simply making select queries in the targeted rows **inside** the transaction (and not before).

Queries running in parallele will automatically wait until the end of the first transaction. Unless you make very long transaction this wait will not be very long, and the process will continue just after the first transaction ends. Unless your treatments takes more than 15s chances are that by aborting your transaction in case of lock, sending a response to your final user and redoing the transaction later, you will loose a loooot more time.

MySQL has a timeout setting for the lock (**lock wait timeout**), you can maybe adjust this timeout to a quite low value (let's say 3s) and you'll get an exception if your lock wait is too long, then you'll have to abort your transaction, but by default let MySQL do the lock & wait managment without breaking the transaction early in case of lock.

Anyway you should have Exception catch loops for your application code to catch for these timeout and for deadlock detection exceptions as well. The classical thing that should be done is that case is restarting the whole transaction until it works but if you want you can as well abort the whole thing and tell you user he should wait (but in 90% of the cases, this is longer than redoing the transaction without taking the user interaction in consideration).

Comment: From what i have read and from what you suggested me I see that the only choise is to set innodb_lock_wait_timeout variable to a small value. But this is a non-elegant manner from my POV. Do you have any other suggestion or that's all? Thanks anyway.

Comment: How long are your transactions?

Comment: for transactions running in a long time you could effectively use the lock wait timeout to maybe 10s and catch this exception (something like timeout lock from the database). Then after retrying your transaction several time (3s) if you still have this lock timeout you can catch it and tell your user he should wait 15 minutes as a long process is blocking edition in database.

Answer (score 0):

**Not a solution, but a work around**

May be you can try adding a status column to your table initial value can be `PENDING`

- Select only records that are `PENDING`
- Update status to `IN-PROGRESS` when you start transaction
- Update to `DONE` when you are done processing the record

If you wanna retry transactions that failed for some reason,
add a `process_start_time` or `updated_at` field and if the status is  `IN-PROGRESS` for longer than expected, you can reset them to `PENDING` or `FAILED` and add a re-try mechanism